# No date is get using bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using this js `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` in implementing datepicker but in angular way. But I wonder why no date is get or when I tried to display what is the selected date but no date is displayed.

Here is my code in using this datepicker.

```
<div class="input-group form-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="md md-event"></i></span>
        <div class="dtp-container dropdown fg-line">
        <input type='text' class="date-picker form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" placeholder="Click here..." name="transaction_date" ng-model="masterlist.transaction_date">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tried to display what is the selected date using this code in angular.

```
{{masterlist.transaction_date}}
```

No display or no value.

What's wrong with this code? what should I modify to make this work? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: can you create plunkr for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `angular material datepicker` instead. Its really easy to implement and use. Here is the working **plunker** for you :

http://plnkr.co/edit/zfY0azlAhD2MjOKm16qy?p=preview

In html:

```
<md-datepicker  ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

Comment: What files do I need to install or download? I am using visual studio, ASP.net

Comment: you can include the CDNs in the particular page you are using, or you can simply include the CDNs in the master page which shares all the scripts file and start working. Files that are required are in the cdns.